# cURL GET service response is blank in SOAPUI

Tags: curl, groovy, get, soapui

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def appToken = "8ry+2bvULHbuYMu75bl80vDBYC3sDbq26JUpCNd19Is="
def downloadURL = "https://api.thetradedesk.com/v3/myreports/view/9411002/538769/1507695066?sig=C0G46d8hyTJGk8blhW8smgo27JzaWDjaNogtVQaJ-Lg."

def result

def process = ["path\\curl.exe", "-X", "GET", downloadURL,
            "-H", "cache-control: no-cache",
            "-H", "postman-token: 21cc8561-8e79-0e85-ad60-ea6e4b69dda2",
            "-H", "ttd-auth:"+appToken]


result = process.execute()
/*def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def jsonSlurper = slurper.parseText(slurper)*/

log.info result.text
```

=======================================
    When i run above groovy script in SOAP UI, it returns blank response while it is working in POSTMAN.

```
Pl. Note: App Token expires in every 5 mins so this token wont be valid after my post, please suggest me how to handle GET response using SOAP UI for cURL request?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your command as a single string where you concatenate variables using + such as:
`def process = "path\\curl.exe -X, GET "+ downloadURL+ "-H, cache-control: no-cache, -H, postman-token: 21cc8561-8e79-0e85-ad60-ea6e4b69dda2, -H, ttd-auth: "+appToken`
after that do a 
`log.info process` to check your command in between creating and running it.